# How to make NSJSONSerialization *NOT* escape "/" character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I have a webserver which accepts dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. I construct the string representation of `NSDate` like this :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyy";
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate new]];
```

The string is fine. However, after the whole server input gets processd through `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: options: error:]` the `/` gets escaped and the result looks like this : `10\/01\/2015`

I do realize that the easiest way is to allow the server to accept other date delimiter (i.e. `-` or `.`) but I'm interested whether there is a way to make `NSJSONSerialization` NOT escape characters.

Comment: You can't fix your server to use a JSON decoder that implements the standard?

Comment: As I said - I know this would be the easiest way to do this. I just couldn't think of a way to "fix" this on my side, and was curious "academically" of the possibilities :)

Comment: The way to do it is to make it not meet the specifications for JSON serialization.